# If else formatting Visual Studio not indenting correctly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, if-statement, formatting

So this is going to be a kind of strange question, I have never run into this formatting issue with any other programs I have written. I think it is because my if statements has multiple || which needed multiple lines to make it appear more readable.

Notice the dotted line under my else if(). It is getting shifted right for some reason under the if instead of the else.

[image]

Is there some kind of formatting setting that can fix this? Or is there a different way I am supposed to do this else if statement? Having all those OR checks is pretty much necessary but I did not wan't to put them all on a single line as that would look real ugly.

Thanks!

Comment: FWIW I would put all those strings into a list and do `.Any(s => test.StartsWith(s))` to make that cleaner.

Comment: That dotted line doesn't seem to be affecting the actual code indentation in any way.  Is this just a minor visual annoyance?  You could also extract the condition itself into a method, removing the need for a multi-line condition.

Comment: Yeah its more a visual annoyance above anything else. I guess I will just extract it into a different method. I just liked the readability of all the || because there is no real good name for the method that I would have to create. It's more just a really long condition check of where to get some data lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting -> New Lines

Uncheck everything and save.

Then, CTRL + E, D to format the document.

Also, you're using a huge compound `if` statement there, which is quite frankly a mess. If you need to check multiple items as starting values, put them all into a list.

```
List<String> ModelNumberPrefixes = new List<String>();
ModelNumberPrefixes.Add("A1C1C");
ModelNumberPrefixes.Add("A1C1D");
//etc

ModelNumberPrefixes.ForEach(s => {
    if (ModelNumber.StartsWith(s)) {
       //Whatever you need to do in your big if block
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I think I am going to go with this route but instead I am going to use .any(s => ModelNumber.StartsWith(s)) like what Bradley suggested above.

Comment: @EricObermuller .any will do the job

Answer (score 2):

To format a selection: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F

To format a document: Ctrl+K, Ctrl+D

See the [pre-defined keyboard shortcuts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/da5kh0wa(v=vs.100)) . (These two are Edit.FormatSelection and Edit.FormatDocument.)